# unity reloading after changing a script

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

If I change c# script and go back to unity-editor 2021 I get 'reload script assemblies' even if I add a space to that script. This is happening when I return from ide to unity-editor so it's can't compile until I switch tab to it. Is it possible to get rid of it? I can turn off auto refresh but I don't want to compile it with hacks like alt+r before entering 'play mode'. I guess the only option to switch back to 2019. I read about unity assembly definition. It takes 1.5 seconds to compile a project from scratch, but it's annoying.

[image]

Comment: `even if I add a space to that script` .. well the compiler doesn't really care about syntax at that point .. the script was changed so it needs to be recompiled ... only after that it would know that it was a minor visual change

Comment: Using assemblies would limit the loading time as Unity would only recompile assemblies that were modified. If you have none, all scripts are into global and all gets recompiled despite modifying one script.

Comment: 2019 did this too, but maybe it didn't bother to show a progress bar. Unity will take the time to recompile anyway after any change to your code.

Comment: I am on linux there is only vs code for free. But visual studio allows to compile that thing in background. Can be a little useful feature